# What do these numbers across the skills mean?

Tags: smite

When watching other players play Smite, the UI sometimes looks different from what I see. For example, in this screenshot, there are extra numbers across Anhur's 4 skills:

[image: Shows Anhur's skill bar with mystery numbers at the top-right corner of each skill.]

I know that the top numbers correspond to the keys you press to use the skill, and the numbers centered on the skill show the remaining cooldown. What do the numbers at the top of the skill box (80, 110, 80, 120) mean, however? I've never seen those when I play.

Comment: Another new change is that (assuming you don't have instacast turned on) when you press the key for an ability, a portion of the mana bar turns purple to indicate how much of it will be used for that ability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those numbers are the [mana cost](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Anhur). There is a setting in the options menu to turn them on, I believe.